# refinishing ceiling with beadboard: insulation underlayer?

Tags: ceiling

We plan to refinish ceiling in 9ft x 9ft office nook. Currently it is finished with some sort of paper-based acoustic tiles. Underneath are rough boards without insulation. Office was an addition so there is virtually no attic access.

I want to use MDF pre-painted 1/4in [beadboard 4x8 panels](https://www.homedepot.com/p/EUCATILE-32-sq-ft-3-16-in-x-48-in-x-96-in-Beadboard-White-True-Bead-Panel-975-759/205669196) to refinish the ceiling. What is the proper way to do that while increasing insulation quality? Is there some sort of insulating underlay that can be installed between rough ceiling and beadboard or I should open up the ceiling and put R30 fiberglass between joists?

[image: office space ceiling]

Comment: *"virtually no attic access."* sounds like there's **some access.** Perhaps enough for blown in?

Comment: If not, and you're redoing the whole ceiling, you could put up sheet-foam insulation and then your surface material over that (with long screws, of course, so it's attached to joists rather than foam)

Answer (score 1):

You can frame down and insulate if you don't mind losing considerable height, or use sheet foam where 4.5 inches of the fancier types claiming to be R7-per-inch would do R30, but you'd better put drywall under that before the beadboard due to fire behavior of foam.

To not lose so much space in the room (and spend less) you'll want to get into the attic space, (cutting an access hole here if need be,) do most of your insulating there, and then you could do a thinner foam sheet to block the thermal break of the framing and drywall. You should have the drywall even if you don't choose to add foam, as MDF beadboard isn't doing anything to protect your ceiling boards and roof framing anyway. But an inch or two of foam here will make significant difference in the overall performance.